# One giant servicer of many services vs. one servicer per service

Tags: microservices, grpc, hot-reload

Setup

- My app uses gRPC for frontend/backend separation
- Backend (server + services) is written in Python

Goals

I'd love to achieve live-updates including:

1. Updating existing services
2. Adding new services
3. Removing services

Problem

I can achieve #1 by using Python's `importlib` feature. But there are fewer options for adding/removing services. It seems to depend on the app's gRPC implementation. The major constraints seem to be the fact that servicers can only be registered before running the server, i.e., through the call to

```py
add_MyServiceServicer_to_server()
```

So does adding reflection support, which is through the call to

```py
service_names = [
    MyService_pb.DESCRIPTOR.services_by_name[''].full_name,
    ...
]

reflection.enable_server_reflection(service_names, my_server)
```

Solution Candidates

- Approach 1: Have one servicer per service, much like [the official `SayHello` example of gRPC](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/tree/master/examples/python/helloworld)
- Approach 2: Have one giant servicer that includes all the other services as its RPC methods.

Approach 1 seems to be intuitive, but it won't support adding/removing services while the server is running.

Approach 2 seems promising, but it is confusing by sticking the entire universe in a single servicer. And I'm not sure how gRPC's thread pool would like this approach.

Questions

- Can I achieve my goals with these approaches?
- If true, which one is better in terms of both maintainability and performance?
- If false, are there alternatives?

Comment: I'm not completely whether it's possible in Python, but it's generally not a good idea to add services to a running server.  Typically microservices would have multiple replicas deployed, and be restarted in a rolling update when new services are added.

Comment: @DougFawley OK, so I suspected that's why they don't allow adding servicers live by default. But is it that RPC servers always reboot if new services are added? What's the best user experience like in this scenario?

Comment: "What's the best user experience like in this scenario?" -> microservice clients should expect and be resilient to RPC failures. They can happen for many other reasons in steady state. Typically you will run multiple replicas and when one is restarted, if you gracefully shut it down, clients will have a chance to create connections to other backends and no RPCs will fail. But if they do fail, clients should retry and will use another backend. Users should not really be impacted by this.

Comment: @DougFawley Thanks a lot. Your tip really helps. I'll turn this into an answer and credit you. 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per @DougFawley's comments,

> Typically microservices would have multiple replicas deployed, and be restarted in a rolling update when new services are added.
>
> "What's the best user experience like in this scenario?" ->
> microservice clients should expect and be resilient to RPC failures.
> They can happen for many other reasons in steady state. Typically you
> will run multiple replicas and when one is restarted, if you
> gracefully shut it down, clients will have a chance to create
> connections to other backends and no RPCs will fail. But if they do
> fail, clients should retry and will use another backend. Users should
> not really be impacted by this.

In short, it's a bad idea to add/remove services without rebooting server. So for this reason, I'd better adopt the one-to-one servicer-service binding and not hack it for this particular live-update intent.

Comment: FWIW, it's totally fine and normal for servers to support multiple services*, but dynamically adding them at runtime shouldn't really be nicessary.

* - example: many servers will enable the reflection service to allow for better interaction with clients like grpcurl, possibly a health checking service, etc.